# React Native Invariant Violation on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

when I tried run my react-native project on android I get this error: `Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.`

I have tried the watchman watch-del-all, and react-native start --reset-cache. But it still does not work. Is there any idea for resolve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: do you have an app entry file (usually app.js or index.js) that's correctly being called?
it would be helpful to share a sample file.

Comment: yes, I have an index.js. It works on ios correctly but it failed on android.```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: try doing a clean npm install by running ```npm ci```

Comment: It does  not work :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill all node process and start npm server and run application:

Step1: run command killall -9 node

> For windows users, run: taskkill /im node.exe
>
> Run taskkill /f /im node.exe if the process still persists.

Step2: run command npm start --reset-cache

Step3: run command react-native run-ios OR react-native run-android

Comment: Hi, I had tried  but it still does not work.

Comment: Try restarting the metro bundler in case if you have not.